# Android adaptor getting into constructor but not creating ListView

Tags: java, android

As the title suggests I am trying to create a list view on my android app.

I have done this in 10+ other places but here I am having a real issue in getting the adapter to work.

I am calling it in my fragment as seen below:

```
private ListView colourOptions;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.change_colour_layout, container, false);

    changeBtn = myView.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    colourOptions = myView.findViewById(R.id.colourOptions);

//        ChangeColourService changeColourService = new ChangeColourService(ChangeColourFragment.this);
//        setListView();

    Log.v("ChangeColour", device.model().versions.toString());

    ColoursAdaptor adaptor = new ColoursAdaptor(device.model().versions, getActivity());

    colourOptions.setAdapter(adaptor);

    Log.v("ChangeColour", "test");

    return myView;
}
```

And then the adaptor:

```
public class ColoursAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Version> {

    public RealmList<Version> dataSet;

    Context mContext;

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    public ColoursAdaptor(RealmList<Version> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.check_row_item);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext=context;

        Log.v("ChangeColour", "in construct");
    }

    private int lastPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Get the data item for this position
        final Version version = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_row_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.checkbox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            result=convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result=convertView;
        }

        lastPosition = position;

        Log.v("ChangeColour", "in here");

        if(version != null){
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

            Log.v("ChangeColour", "in adapter");

            viewHolder.checkbox.setText(version.colour.title);

            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                }
            });
        }

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I get 3 logs out at the end, the list of versions, the confirmation that I am in the constructor and then test. But nothing from the one in the main part of the adaptor:

```
RealmList<Version>@[74,75,76,77,78,79]
in construct
test
```

The screen stays blank as the adaptor hasn't created the `ListView` there is something obvious missing but I just can't put my finger on it

Help appreciated

Comment: You need to set up your view in `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: Could you provide some more information, that doesn't mean too much to me

Comment: You need to override `onBindViewHolder` and set the view's values there.

Comment: Please explain with an answer, I have no idea what that is or does, simply saying use it is not constructive

Comment: post your adapter's whole code.

Comment: Devendra, it is there